# wait_event_timeout equivalent in U-boot

Tags: c, arm, linux-device-driver, u-boot

I am looking for wait_event_timeout[1] equivalent function in u-boot but could not find the same.

is there such fuction do exist in u-boot ?

[1] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/wait.h#L371

Answer (score 1):

U-Boot runs with a single process and a single thread. Interrupts are not enabled for many platforms. So a function like wait_event_timeout() cannot be implemented.

Instead you will have to create a loop that constantly checks if the event has occurred and in the loop execute whatever it takes to let the event occur.

For example look at the efi_wait_for_event() function which in a loop calls efi_timer_check(). efi_timer_check() runs all registered timer based functions like checking the network interface for received packages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am wondering if readx_poll_timeout can be used to emulate same behavior as of "wait_event_timeout" ?

Comment: @Milan, and who will assert the event? If you have UP system with IRQ disabled, there is no way it can assert you an event. For such thing you may need thread / multi-task support and at least IRQ enabled with some source of the periodical interrupts (and this will require some scheduler to be written).